# Show that $\zeta'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I started with the functional equation which was derived in class,
$$
\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)
$$
and took the logarithmic derivative of both sides to get
$$
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\ln2+\ln\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})}+\psi(1-s)-\frac{\zeta'(1-s)}{\zeta(1-s)}.
$$
Now I see that if I evaluate at $1$ or $0$ I will have an equation for $\zeta'(0)$ but I cannot solve either of the resulting equations. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: you don't need the functional equation, and I don't think you know how to  prove it. HINT  (assuming you know that $\eta(0) = 1/2$) : $\eta(s) = \sum_{n= 1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s} = s \int_0^\infty S(x) x^{-s-1} dx$ with $S(x) = \sum_{n \le x} (-1)^{n+1}$, hence
$\eta'(s) = \int_0^\infty S(x) x^{-s-1} dx-s\int_0^\infty \ln(x) S(x) x^{-s-1} dx$

Comment: sorry not sure my hint was a so good hint. if you'd like to use the functional equation, you have to look at the pole at $s=0$ of $\frac{\pi}{2}\tan(\pi s/2)$ and of $\frac{\zeta'(1-s)}{\zeta(1-s)}$, and estimate the residual constant term of their respective Laurent series

Comment: For some reason the r.h.s also equals $\int_0^1\ln{\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x$, an integral which is perhaps easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We may use the $\eta $ function as suggested by user1952009. Given $s\in(0,1)$,
$$ \eta(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} $$
fulfills $\lim_{s\to 0^+}\eta(s)=-\frac{1}{2}$ by Abel's lemma. On the other hand,
$$ \eta'(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \log n}{n^s}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}-e^{-nu}}{u}\,du $$
by differentiation under the $\sum$ sign and [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html). So we have:
$$ \lim_{s\to 0^+}\eta'(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}e^{-u}+\frac{1}{1+e^u}}{u}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{\pi}{2}$$
by Wallis' product and Frullani's theorem again. On the other hand,
$$ \zeta(s) = (2^{1-s}-1)\,\eta(s) $$
so $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ and by switching to logarithmic derivatives we get:
$$ \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \frac{\eta'(s)}{\eta(s)}-\frac{2^{1-s}\log(2)}{2^{1-s}-1}$$
from which $\zeta'(0)=-\log\sqrt{2\pi}$ easily follows.

Comment: This is what I got, for some reason I get the negative of what I want. \begin{equation*}\begin{split} \zeta(s)        &=(2^{1-s}-1)\eta(s)\\
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}    &=\frac{\eta'(s)}{\eta(s)}-\frac{2^{1-s}\log(2)}{2^{1-s}-1}\\
\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)}    &=\frac{\eta'(0)}{\eta(0)}-\frac{2^{1-0}\log(2)}{2^{1-0}-1}\\
\zeta'(0)        &=\zeta(0)\left(\frac{\eta'(0)}{\eta(0)}-2\log2\right)\\
\implies \zeta'(0)      &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\log\frac{\pi}{2}-2\log2\right)\\ \end{split}\end{equation*}

Comment: My definition of $\eta(s)$ is slightly different from the usual one due to the $(-1)^n$ factor.

Comment: The usual Dirichlet $\eta$-function is defined through $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{\color{red}{n-1}}}{n^s}$, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio I deleted my previous comment, thanks to you for your answer.

Comment: I believe that $\zeta(s)=(2^{1-s} - 1) \eta(s)$ should instead be $\eta(s)=(2^{1-s} - 1) \zeta(s)$